# Get a list of members of a WinNT group

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, active-directory-group, windows-security

There are a couple of questions similar to this on stack overflow but not quite the same.

I want to open, or create, a local group on a win xp computer and add members to it, domain, local and well known accounts.  I also want to check whether a user is already a member so that I don't add the same account twice, and presumably get an exception.

So far I started using the DirectoryEntry object with the `WinNT://` provider.  This is going ok but I'm stuck on how to get a list of members of a group?

Anyone know how to do this?  Or provide a better solution than using DirectoryEntry?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Okay, it's taken a while, messing around with different solutions but the one that fits best with my original question is given below.  I can't get the DirectoryEntry object to access the members of a local group using the 'standard' methods, the only way I could get it to enumerate the members was by using the Invoke method to call the native objects Members method.

```
using(DirectoryEntry groupEntry = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://./Administrators,group"))
{
    foreach(object member in (IEnumerable) groupEntry.Invoke("Members"))
    {
        using(DirectoryEntry memberEntry = new DirectoryEntry(member))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(memberEntry.Path);
        }
    }
}
```

I also used a similar technique to add and remove members from the local group.

Hopefully this helps someone else as well.
Keith.

**EDIT** by Tim: added VB.Net version

```
Public Function MembersOfGroup(ByVal GroupName As String) As List(Of DirectoryEntry)
    Dim members As New List(Of DirectoryEntry)
    Try
        Using search As New DirectoryEntry("WinNT://./" & GroupName & ",group")
            For Each member As Object In DirectCast(search.Invoke("Members"), IEnumerable)
                Dim memberEntry As New DirectoryEntry(member)
                members.Add(memberEntry)
            Next
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
    Return members
End Function
```

Comment: Its NOT working showing this error  : Error 4 Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' requires '1' type arguments C:\Documents and Settings\pratikj\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs 112 44 ConsoleApplication1
Can you please help me out ??

Comment: I know its a little late but you need to use System.Collections.IEnumerable

Answer (score 7):

Microsoft .NET Framework provides a standard library for working with Active Directory: **[System.DirectoryServices namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682458(VS.85).aspx)** in the System.DirectoryServices.dll.

Microsoft recommends using two main classes from the System.DirectoryServices namespace: **DirectoryEntry** and **DirectorySearcher**. In most cases, it is enough to use DirectorySearcher class only.

> *UPDATE: I tested it on my machine - it works. But maybe I've misunderstood
>   your question.*

Here is an example from an excellent [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/QueryADwithDotNet.aspx):

### Get a list of users belonging to a particular AD group

```
using System.DirectoryServices;

ArrayList GetADGroupUsers(string groupName)
{    
   SearchResult result;
   DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher();
   search.Filter = String.Format("(cn={0})", groupName);
   search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("member");
   result = search.FindOne();

   ArrayList userNames = new ArrayList();
   if (result != null)
   {
       for (int counter = 0; counter < 
          result.Properties["member"].Count; counter++)
       {
           string user = (string)result.Properties["member"][counter];
               userNames.Add(user);
       }
   }
   return userNames;
}
```

Comment: I think your code only works for active directory groups.  I need to get the members of a 'local' group.  Like the local Adminstrators group that is setup on all Windows installations, maybe not Vista.

Comment: I tried both of these to get the members of a local group.  The accepted answer worked for me, and the answer you gave did not.  I'm sure that it works just fine for an AD group, but I got an error saying that searches weren't supported for WinNT:// objects.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find this information inside the [`"member"` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677097(VS.85).aspx) on the `DirectoryEntry` that represents the group.